# In JPA QL,How can I select all country by item's category?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Model

```
Item(id,name,countries,category)
Category(id,name)
Country(id,name)
```

Some thing like this (incorrect)

```
select distinct c 
from Country c left join Weapon w on c in(w.countries) 
where w.weaponCategory = :category
```

I don't want to do this in code,fetch by category and iterate,but how to write this JPA QL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use join:

```
select distinct c from Weapon w left join w.countries c where w.weaponCategory = :category
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is simple than I thought,

```
select distinct w.countries 
from Weapon w where w.weaponCategory = :category
```

This is my first time write JPA QL.